# Alt text showing in IE and firefox but not in safari?

Tags: xhtml, safari

Why Alt text not showing in Safari ?

http://gregory.pakosz.fr/stackoverflow/homework.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is fine. Safari simply doesn't support `alt` (I find it baffling).

Comment: toh, then mac user can not see alt text if images are disabled. is there a way to enable it?

Comment: AFAIK there's no way to enable proper `alt` support (you'd have to hack it with scripts, which probably isn't worth the hassle). Safari doesn't have user-accessible option to disable images. You could add `title`, which will let users figure out what is what via tooltips.

Comment: Not quite true. Safari displays the alt text as long as it fits into a single line within the designated image area.